# In Core Java - Read Multiple XML Files form Multiple Folders and append in One XML file

Tags: java, xml, saxon

1. This is My main Driectory Path: C:\JavaPractice\Task3\Process\test\
2. In the above main directory I have multiple subfolders and each subfolder contains a "tud.xml".
3. Need to crawl each tud.xml and extract the "< deg >" tag from that XML file.
4. if < deg > tag contains more than one degree (ex: < deg >MSC, PHD< /deg >) then split each degree into separate line.
5. Append it in a single output file called deg.xml and unique and sort. (please note that output file does not contain duplicate words)

My Code:

```
    import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
    import net.sf.saxon.lib.NamespaceConstant;
    import net.sf.saxon.om.NodeInfo;
    import net.sf.saxon.om.TreeInfo;
    import net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
    import javax.xml.xpath.*;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.TreeMap;


    public class Task3 {

        private static String[] ParaToSentenc(String PtS) {
            String[] strArray = PtS.split(",");
            return strArray;
        }


        private static List<String> UniqueAndSortWord(String[] UW) {
            List<String> unique_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
            Map<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for(String word : UW) {
                if(!hMap.containsKey(word)) { 
                    hMap.put(word,"");
                    unique_sort.add(word);
                }        
            }
            Collections.sort(unique_sort);
            return unique_sort;
        }

        private static void FileWriter(String content, String outputfile) {
            File file = new File(outputfile);
            FileWriter writer = null;
            BufferedWriter bw = null;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(file);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                bw.write(content);
                bw.flush();
                bw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");;
            }
        }       

        public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
            String Inputname = args[0];//sc.nextLine(); //"D:\\document.xml";
            String outputname = args[1];//sc.nextLine(); //"D:\\document.txt";
            Task3.runApp(Inputname, outputname);
            System.out.println("Success");
        }

        /**
         * Run the application
         */


        private static void runApp(String filename, String outputfile) throws Exception {


            /////////////////////////////////////////////
            // The following initialization code is specific to Saxon
            // Please refer to SaxonHE documentation for details
            System.setProperty("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:"+
                               NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON,
                               "net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl");

            XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.
                                     newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON);
            XPath xpExpression = xpFactory.newXPath();
            System.err.println("Loaded XPath Provider " + xpExpression.getClass().getName());

            // Build the source document.
            InputSource inputSrc = new InputSource(new File(filename).toURL().toString());
            SAXSource saxSrc = new SAXSource(inputSrc);
            Configuration config = ((XPathFactoryImpl) xpFactory).getConfiguration();
            TreeInfo treeInfo = config.buildDocumentTree(saxSrc);
            // End Saxon specific code
            /////////////////////////////////////////////


            XPathExpression findwtTags =
                                        xpExpression.compile("count(//deg)");


            Number countResults = (Number)findwtTags.evaluate(treeInfo, XPathConstants.NUMBER);


            // Get a list of the <deg> Tags
            // The following expression gets a set of nodes that have a <deg> Tags,
            // then extracts the text node from the <deg> tags
            XPathExpression findwtTextNodes =
                                             xpExpression.compile("//deg");



            //global string

            String global = "";

            List resultNodeList = (List) findwtTextNodes.evaluate(treeInfo, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            if (resultNodeList != null) {
                int count = resultNodeList.size();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    NodeInfo cNode = (NodeInfo) resultNodeList.get(i);
                    String name = cNode.getStringValue();
                    global = global + "\n" + name;
                }
            }


            //Full content text...
            String globalText = "Full Degree content:" + global + "\n\n";


            // Para To Sentence...
            String[] strSenArray = ParaToSentenc(global);
            globalText = globalText + "Each Degree separated in line by line:\n";
    //        globalText = globalText + "Sentence Count : "+strSenArray.length+"\n";
            for(int i=0; i<strSenArray.length; i++){
                globalText = globalText + strSenArray[i].trim() + "\n";
            }
            globalText = globalText + "\n";



            //Unique Words
            List<String> strUniqueList = UniqueAndSortWord(strSenArray);
            globalText = globalText + "Unique Degree list:\n";
            for(String word : strUniqueList){
                globalText = globalText + word.trim() + "\n";
            }
            globalText = globalText.substring(0, globalText.length()-1);
            globalText = globalText + "\n\n";

            //All Text wtite into file...
            FileWriter(globalText, outputfile);
        }



    }
```

Comment: Which part[s] are you having trouble with?

Comment: I do not know how to read multiple xml files one by one.

Comment: Also my sort function is not working

Comment: It would be helpful if you managed to isolate the question and example code to the single  issue you are having, insted of listing all code at once. E.g. if your xpath works  - leave it out of the question.

Also - by breaking up the problem into small tasks and be able to test each task via a Unit Test is super-helpful when dealing with new stuff you are learning how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in one XPath expression with XPath 3.1:

```
(collection('file:///C:/JavaPractice/Task3/Process/test?select=tud.xml;recurse=yes') //deg 
! tokenize(., ',')) => distinct-values() => sort())))
```

All the Java needs to do is run this expression and process the resulting sequence of strings.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I am learing Java. that is the reason I expecting solution in java

Comment: I suspected from the name "JavaPractice" that this might be the case (that's why I didn't propose XSLT). However, you are already using two languages (Java plus XPath), so regardless of the learning objectives, it makes sense to use each of the two languages for the part of the problem that it's best at.